# Using encoded target value

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, encoding, linear-regression

I have a pandas dataframe and one column of it is my target value which is categorical.

I used get_dummies for encoding my target value. Now, I have my encoded target value in 5 encoded column because my target value has 5 categories.

My question is that how can I consider all of these 5 columns in linear regression method?

I have x_dummies as my dependent values dataframe and y_dummies as my target value data frame with 5 columns of encoded values.

I have never had a target value in more than one column!
Is this correct?

Link to Assingment:
https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/ordinal_tech_report.pdf

```py
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit( x_dummies_training, y_dummies_training)
```

Comment: Why are you using one-hot encoding for your target just because you have multiple classes?

Comment: @gmds Its part of homework to encode with get_dummies

Answer (score 1):

If your target is categorical you may want to use a classifier , not a regressor.
You may read [this article](https://medium.com/quick-code/regression-versus-classification-machine-learning-whats-the-difference-345c56dd15f7) to understand the difference if you want .
So in your case you would want to use a classifier and keep your y target as one variable instead of one hot encoding it.
If you want a mathematical model that's easy to interpret ( i guessed that from your use of Linear Regression) you may want a multinomial logistic regression:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs',
    multi_class='multinomial').fit(X, y)
```

You may want to check the sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) .
You could also try the wildly popular boosting trees methods that should give you better results : check [catboost](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html) as an example .

Comment: Based on what is asked in my assignment, I should encode target value with get_dummies so they will not be categorical

Comment: do you mind copying your assignment , would make it a lot easier to help you

Comment: I added that. I have a dataframe ( Kaggle salary prediction). I was asked to----> Transform your ordinal categorical target variable (k salary buckets) into (k-1) binary classification problems, see, e.g., Figure 2 in the link